# Is Entity Framewok installed with my Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed on my machine. I am new to EF. Kindly guide me is EF (code first and model first) installed on my machine or I will need to install it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NuGet and install it: http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework  NuGet will keep you up to date. As **hvd** mentioned, it's the newest version that supports code first.

Comment: do I need to install it even for dbfirst ?

Comment: For completeness: Visual Studio does come with Entity Framework (runtime is included in .NET Framework, the files for the designer are installed as part of VS), but it's not the newest version that supports Code First.